# Give a lower bound for $\frac{(a+b)^2}{ab}$ a,b>0

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Give a lower bound for $\frac{(a+b)^2}{ab}$?

Approach 1 : $\frac{a+b}{2} \geq \sqrt{ab}$ (A.M $\geq$ G.M)

By simplification, $\frac{(a+b)^2}{ab} \geq 4$.

Approach 2: $\frac{a^2 + b^2 + 2ab}{3} \geq (a^2b^2(2ab))^{1/3}$

$(a+b)^2 \geq 3(ab) \cdot (2)^{1/3}$

$\frac{(a+b)^2}{ab} \geq 3(2^{1/3})$.

What's wrong ? I got a value of $3.77$, which is less than $4$. But, $4$ seems to be right.

Comment: Lower bounds are not unique. It can be shown that the *greatest* lower bound is 4, so any number less than 4 is also a lower bound.

Comment: One should also note that the bound $4$ obviously can be  attained.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: You can only use the Arithmetic Mean - Geometric Mean Inequality in this case if $a, b$ are positive real numbers since division by zero is undefined.  You should specify what assumptions you are making in the statement of the problem.

Comment: I mentioned that I am using A.M-G.M inequality in the body. That implies that a,b are non-negative real numbers. Sorry for not providing enough information in the title.

Comment: As an alternative by rearrangement $$\frac{(a+b)^2}{ab}=\frac{a^2+2ab+b^2}{ab}=\frac a b+\frac b a+2\ge 4$$

Comment: @HarishRavi You can edit the question and add that a, b are non-negative real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The optimal lower bound is 4:

Let $f(x) = \frac{(x+b)^2}{xb}$ (with $x=a$ for the sake of common notations). For every $x$ not equal to $0$, $f'(x) = \frac{(x+b)(x-b)}{x^2b}$. You find out that $f'$ is strictly negative on $]0,b]$ and strictly positive on $[b, + \infty[$, meaning that $f$ is strictly decreasing on $]0,b]$ and strictly increasing on $[b, + \infty[$, so the lower value take by $f$ is at $x=b$, and $f(b) = \frac{4b^2}{b^2} = 4$.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

We have $$A=\frac{(a+b)^2}{ab}=\frac{a^2+2ab+b^2}{ab}=\frac ab+2+\frac ba$$
By setting $a=xb$ we obtain $A(x)=x+\frac1x+2$.

But $$A'(x)=1-\frac 1{x^2}\\A'(x_0)=0\Rightarrow x_0=1$$

So $A(x)$ is decreasing for $x\in (0,1]$ and increasing for $x \in [1,+\infty)$ with minimum in $x_0=1$, the $A(1)=4$.

Thus, $A=\frac{(a+b)^2}{ab}\ge4$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you for the heads up-will edit the $A'(x_0)$. As for the "the", it refers to the value of $A(1)$ so I think it's grammatically correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since the *global minimum* is $4$, this means that all the lower bounds are less or equal than $4$ .

---

If $a,b\in\mathbb R^{+}$ then you have :

$$
\begin{align}&(a-b)^2≥0\\
\iff &(a+b)^2≥4ab\\
\iff &\frac {(a+b)^2}{ab}≥4\thinspace .\end{align}
$$

In this case, the equality holds iff, when $a=b$ .

But, we know that the following is also correct :

$$
\begin{align}\frac{a^2 + b^2 + 2ab}{3}&≥\sqrt [3]{2a^3b^3}=ab\sqrt [3]{2}\end{align}
$$

or

$$\frac{(a+b)^2}{ab}≥3\sqrt [3]{2}$$

The point is, in this case the equality is *not* possible. Because,

$$
\begin{align}&a^2=b^2=2ab\\
\implies &2a^2=a^2\vee 2b^2=b^2\\
\implies &(a,b)\in\emptyset\end{align}
$$

This implies that, you have :

$$\frac{(a+b)^2}{ab}\color{red}{>}3\sqrt [3]{2}$$

which is consistent .